# HTML table exported to .xls fails to open when using FireFox to download

Tags: javascript, html, excel, firefox, xls

I am using a function that I found on here on stackoverflow.  It works fine on Internet Explorer and Google Chrome, but when used in FireFox, the downloaded file is unable to be opened in Excel.  When I double click it or open from Excel, it displays a blank workbook.  When I convert this downloaded file from .xls to .html, it opens properly in any browser previously mentioned.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

```
function fnExcelReport(){
var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
var textRange; var j=0;
var tab = document.getElementById('GroupMembersTable'); // id of table
var sa
for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
{     
    tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
    //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
}

tab_text= tab_text+"</table>";
tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,""); // remove if u want images in your table
tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // removes input params

var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
{
    txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
    txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
    txtArea1.document.close();
    txtArea1.focus(); 
    sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"SecurityAudit.xls");
}  
else { //other browser not tested on IE 11
    sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  
}
return (sa);
}
```

Comment: is there any difference you can see on a diff on the files you create with chrome and firefox?

Comment: the chrome file has the file name "download" while the firefox download as a random string of characters.  Both have the .xls extension.  Both, when converted to html, display the same in browsers

Comment: try something like https://www.diffchecker.com/diff : if they are 100% identical, they should behave identically.

Comment: I opened both .xls files using notepad and copy pasted the contents into the link you provided.  It says that no differences were detected which now really confuses me...

Comment: strange. the only other thing i can think of is that maybe the content-encoding is wrong on one of them.

Comment: If something like that is the case, what would be the way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue due to a recent windows security update.  The downloaded file is being marked as blocked.  You need to go the the file properties, and click the button Unblock, and then the file opens in Excel.  Excel will no longer open files marked as blocked on my workstation.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this security "issue", disabling the protected view for files from internet (trusted zone, excel options) on the computer or workstation.

If you download the file can unblock but if you choose open file directly from excel don't work until you maid the disabling process i mention at the beginning.